# A simple circuit to turn on door LED when someone visit me

Tags: led, relay, circuit-design

I want a simple circuit do an alarm light that tell me someone visited me.
When someone visits me and in the case no one answer the door, I want to know that.

So I want a press button switch outside the door that will turn on a LED inside the house and will not turn off until I reset it inside the house.
How simple that can be done?

Best to make use of my existing rechargeable USB battery that is used for phones.

Comment: Is that your question - "How simple that can be done?"

Comment: if the button also operates the door bell we need to understand your doorbell before we can make a detailed suggestion.

Comment: no need for a door bell. Just keep light up the LED so I know someone visited me before.

Comment: want the simplest way. Is this circuit hard to do so?

Comment: What Jasen is asking, is how do you plan to activate the circuit. Are you connecting it to your door bell? Or will you have a second separate button next to the door bell people will press

Comment: I already have a door bell purchased. I want them separated. But if it is simple enough to wire it together. That will also be useful. In this case, you can simply answer the separate case that is already useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

Before you get there through, break down your project into smaller parts.

Start by learning how to turn on an LED using a button to activate a mosfet.

Then add the latch. And finally a battery (don't recommend using rechargeable one for safety).

Comment: If you make a latch circuit using something like a 74HC00 you can drive the LED directly as long as you limit the current, no need for a MOSFET/BJT

Comment: Good point by @Doodle. Also remember to use a current limiting resistor for your LED.

Comment: Why not rechargeable battery, it now can be used to light up a USB LED after inserting into it. Its output is typically 3.7V

Comment: So it is just a circuit including the followings:- battery source, IC, limiting resistor, a push button and and a on/off switch(inside house to reset) and a LED. And that is "done"???

Comment: @DriveCarefully how are you going to recharge the battery once it's depleted though? Li-ion batteries found inside phones are not a trivial task to charge safely...

Comment: ... also there are multiple ways to accomplish this, the way I was thinking involves 2 IC's, 5 resistors, 2 push buttons and 3 capacitors. But that's just one idea of many possible solutions

Comment: I will use portable rechargeable battery, that has a enclosure itself. Not that inside the phone. Also, it will last long enough as it will not be switched on most of the time.

Comment: So using 2 IC is the simplest way?

Comment: I think a on-off switch is better , when off, there is no power and it is reset. Then I set it ON again and it wait for someone to press the push button. It saves one IC ?

Comment: You need two 74HC00 to make the NAND latch circuit I'm talking about. By using a toggle switch you can't just remove one of the chips...